# Spring AOP does not work with self-invocation such as @CachePut

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop

I'm working on Spring caching annotation, but i found some weird things happening in it.

Say I am calling a method in the same service class that has @CachePut annotation in it. That is not getting cached.

If i move that method to some other service implementation file and calling that method caching is working.

I need to know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: AOP is the behind hero to support cache feature. Spring aop generally use cglib or java proxy, which will make a proxy for the target bean. so invoke from outer will come throw the proxy, inner invoke in target bean will in direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you write the following class with `@CachePut` ,

```
public class FooBean implements Foo{

    @CachePut
    public String doSomething(){

    }
}
```

Spring behind scene will create an AOP proxy that wrap your class such that it can apply some caching magic codes before or after calling the actual `@CachePut` method. You can think the AOP proxy looks likes :

```
public class FooBeanProxy implements Foo{

    private FooBean fooBean;

    public String doSomething(){

        //Maybe there are some caching magic codes here....
        fooBean.doSomething()
        //Maybe there are other caching magic codes here........
    }
}
```

> If i move that method to some other service implementation file and
>   calling that method caching is working.

Suppose you do the following in order to call `@CachePut` method:

```
@Component
public class App {

    //FooBeanProxy actually injected HERE
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    public void startDoing(){
        foo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

What Spring injects for you is `FooBeanProxy`,but not your FooBean. So, when you call that `@CachePut` method , the caching magic codes will run as you are calling `FooBeanProxy`

> Say I am calling a method in the same service class that has @CachePut
>   annotation in it. That is not getting cached.

That means it is self-invocation . What you are invoking is **this** reference , which is your `FooBean` instance but not that `FooBeanProxy` anymore. So those caching magic will never be executed and hence the result will not be cached.

Actually ,what I talk above are already mentioned in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). If you still want to have `@CachePut` to take effect in the self-invocation case , you can use the horrible and  ugly `AopContext.currentProxy()` solution mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) or use `AspectJ`.

Comment: Given the exact scenario you described, how do you get this to work if the method doSomething() is a private method?